# What is the starting index of a List in PowerBuilder language?

Tags: list, powerbuilder

Arrays in PB have a starting index of 1. So, do Lists also follow the same or are they different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerScript has no "List" datatype. You may implement it using an unbounded array. Default start index of arrays in PowerScript is 1. You may provide different values:

```
string Department[10]        // Same array bounds
string Department[1 TO 10]   // Same array bounds
string Department[0 TO  9]   // Zero-based array
string Department[-10 TO -1] // Negative indexes are valid
string Department[-3 TO 6]   // "Mixed"  indexes are valid
string Department[ ]         // Unbounded, always start at 1, dynamic size
```

NOTE: Beware of performance using unbounded arrays!

Comment: PowerScript has no *native* list type, but you can add it as a PBNI extension (C++ compiled). You have also hash table and regex. See http://sebastien.kirche.free.fr/powerbuilder/en.html#pbni